# Why does perf show that sleep takes all cores?

Tags: linux, unix, profiling, perf

I am trying to familiarize myself with `perf` and run it against various programs I wrote.

When I launch it against program that is 100% single threaded, perf shows that it takes two cores on machine (task-clock event).
Here's the example output:

```
perf stat  -a --per-core python3 test.py

Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

    S0-C0           1       19004.951263      task-clock (msec) # 1.000 CPUs utilized            (100.00%)
    S0-C0           1              5,582      context-switches                                              (100.00%)
    S0-C0           1                 19      cpu-migrations                                                (100.00%)
    S0-C0           1              3,746      page-faults                                                 
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      cycles                   
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      instructions             
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      branches                 
    S0-C0           1    <not supported>      branch-misses            
    S0-C1           1       19004.950059      task-clock (msec) # 1.000 CPUs utilized            (100.00%)
    S0-C1           1              6,752      context-switches                                              (100.00%)
    S0-C1           1                 25      cpu-migrations                                                (100.00%)
    S0-C1           1                935      page-faults                                                 
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      cycles                   
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      instructions             
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      branches                 
    S0-C1           1    <not supported>      branch-misses            

      19.004688019 seconds time elapsed
```

It even shows that simple `sleep` command takes two cores on my computer and I can't explain this. I understand that OS scheduler can reassign active core for any process, but in this case CPU utilization would reflect that.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: `-a` option of perf-stat (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html) is for system-wide profiling while the command is running. Use it like `perf stat -a sleep 10` to profile system for 10 seconds. To get stats only of your command don't use `-a` option of perf stat: `perf stat python3 test.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to man page of `perf stat` subocmmand, you have `-a` option to profile full system:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html

```
   -a, --all-cpus
       system-wide collection from all CPUs (default if no target is
       specified)
```

In this "system-wide" mode `perf stat` (and [`perf record` too](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html)) will count events on (or profile for `record`) all CPUs in the system. When used without additional argument of `command`, perf will run until interrupted by Ctrl-C. With argument of `command`, perf will count/profile until the command works. Typical usage is

```
perf stat -a sleep 10      # Profile counting every CPU for 10 seconds
perf record -a sleep 10    # Profile with cycles every CPU for 10 seconds to perf.data
```

For getting stats of single command use single process profiling (without -a option)

```
perf stat python3 test.py
```

For profiling (`perf record`) you may run without -a option; or you may use -a and later do some manual filtering in [`perf report`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html), focusing only on the pids/tids/dsos of your application (This can be very useful if command to profile uses some interprocess requests to other daemons to do lot of CPU work).

`--per-core, -A, -C <cpulist>, --per-socket` options are only for system-wide `-a` mode. Try `--per-thread` with `-p pid` attach to process option.

Comment: `perf stat --per-core python3 test.py` does not work for me saying that per core stats only available in system-wide mode. My original goal was to check per core CPU load for some process, but it seems that perf can't do that.