# Is it possible to measure the cycles consumed by a single process on a per-core basis?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I recently saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894497/why-does-perf-show-that-sleep-takes-all-cores#comment74856911_43905532), which asks whether it is possible to measure per-core CPU load for a process, but there has been no reply to it, so I am asking it as a question.

**Is there a mechanism for measuring the cycles used by a single process on a per-core basis?**

More specifically, I'd like the measure at regular intervals (let's say each second), the same way that perf does, but it is not necessary to use perf. That is, something similar to the output of `perf stat -I 500 -e cycles sleep 5`, but with one line for each CPU indicating the number of cycles that the process ran on that CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not quite possible.

You can either measure cycles on a per-core / per-CPU basis for all processes (system wide mode, may require special permissions):

```
# per logical CPU / hardware thread
perf stat -a --no-aggr sleep 1
# per core
perf stat -a --per-core sleep 1
```

Or you can monitor per thread for a given process

```
perf --per-thread -p <pid>
```

Oddly enough `perf` does accept the combination of `--per-core -a -p` - but the result is bogus, which seems like a bug either way.

You might be able to piece something together using bcc / BPF. See https://github.com/iovisor/bcc#tools / http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html. I'm sure there exist a one-liner somehow, but it might not be trivial to find.